# A continuous function on the disk without non-tangential limits

Tags: gn.general-topology, cv.complex-variables

By Fatou's theorem every bounded holomorphic function on the unit disk has non-tangential limits almost everywhere on the unit circle $\mathbb T$.
Is there an explicit example of a bounded continuous function on the disk without non-tangential limits but with radial limits everywhere?

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to have something oscillating faster and faster as one approaches the boundary, such as $f(re^{i\theta}) = \sin ( (1 - r)^{-1})$ ? I admit that I have not thought through how one might show this has no non-tangential limits, so this is merely a suggestion rather than an answer

Comment: @YemonChoi: yes, that works.

Comment: @Yemon Choi Sure. Thanks. Actually I wanted to have some of these functions without non-tangential limits, but with radial limits everywhere.

Comment: @ray OK, that is certainly more subtle. Perhaps you'd like to edit your question to impose this extra restriction?

Comment: @Yemon Choi sure; just added this restriction.

Comment: I don't understand. Aren't radial limits a special kind of non-tangential limits?

Comment: @ Nik Weaver If the non-tangential limit exists, then of course the radial limit at the cusp of that cone at $e^{i\theta}$ exists, but not the other way round. The "limit" (if it exists), depends in general on the angle on how one approaches the cusp.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$
f(z)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2}}\right),
$$
which is a classical example of a function analytic in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, with radial limits everywhere on the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$, and with no non-tangential limit at 1 when the angle of approach with respect to the real axis is larger than $\pi/4$. With $1-z=re^{i\theta}$, its real part is
$$
\operatorname{Re}(f)(z)=e^{-r^{-2}\cos(2\theta)}\cos(r^{-2}\sin(2\theta)),
$$
whose limits on $\mathbb{T}$ have the same properties as above. Then, the real continuous function
$$\arctan(\operatorname{Re}(f))$$
has the same properties as $f$, but it is also bounded.